# Dual boot - Windows 8 and Ubuntu - restore Windows and install Ubuntu properly

Tags: dual-boot, system-installation, restore

I've tried to install Ubuntu on my laptop (HP Pavilion g6) since I have to use a program which only runs in Linux.

For that I tried dual boot Ubuntu alongside Windows using this how-to (https://www.intowindows.com/dual-boot-windows-8-and-ubuntu); i.e. I've created space on my D drive (Windows are on C drive), cca. 100gb A drive.

After the computer booted into Ubuntu, the installation part was fine, till it made me create EFI System partition (installation stated there was no ESP detected, even though I have Windows).

After searching through forums, I've decided to create a 500 mb partition. Ubuntu finally seemed to install, but it still showed the install .exe(dont know the Linux term).

Restarting my laptop, laptop behaved as if I did not install Ubuntu. I've then tried to remove USB where the .iso file is, which made it run 'a stop job is running' in grub. Today I ran Boot repair, and got the next result. My point is, I want to return Windows and then dual boot correctly.

**=== Boot Info Summary ===**

=> Grub2 (v2.00) is installed in the MBR of /dev/sda and looks at sector 1 of
the same hard drive for core.img. core.img is at this location and looks
for (,msdos5)/boot/grub. It also embeds following components:

```
modules
fshelp ext2 part_msdos biosdisk
```

=> Syslinux MBR (4.04-4.07) is installed in the MBR of /dev/sdb.

sda1:

```
File system:       ntfs
Boot sector type:  Windows 8/2012: NTFS
Boot sector info:  No errors found in the Boot Parameter Block.
Operating System:  
Boot files:        /bootmgr /Boot/BCD
```

sda2:

```
File system:       ntfs
Boot sector type:  Windows 8/2012: NTFS
Boot sector info:  No errors found in the Boot Parameter Block.
Operating System:  
Boot files:        /bootmgr /Windows/System32/winload.exe
```

sda3:

```
File system:       ntfs
Boot sector type:  Windows 7/2008: NTFS
Boot sector info:  No errors found in the Boot Parameter Block.
Operating System:  
Boot files:
```

sda4:

```
File system:       Extended Partition
Boot sector type:  Unknown
Boot sector info:
```

sda5:

```
File system:       ext4
Boot sector type:  Grub2 (v1.99-2.00)
Boot sector info:  Grub2 (v2.00) is installed in the boot sector of sda5 
                   and looks at sector 1264615152 of the same hard drive 
                   for core.img. core.img is at this location and looks 
                   for (,msdos5)/boot/grub. It also embeds following 
                   components:
                   
                   modules
                   -------------------------------------------------------
                   fshelp ext2 part_msdos biosdisk
                   -------------------------------------------------------
Operating System:  Ubuntu 18.04.2 LTS
Boot files:        /boot/grub/grub.cfg /etc/fstab 
                   /boot/grub/i386-pc/core.img
```

sda6:

```
File system:       vfat
Boot sector type:  FAT32
Boot sector info:  No errors found in the Boot Parameter Block.
Operating System:  
Boot files:        /EFI/ubuntu/grub.cfg /EFI/BOOT/fbx64.efi 
                   /EFI/ubuntu/fwupx64.efi /EFI/ubuntu/grubx64.efi 
                   /EFI/ubuntu/mmx64.efi /EFI/ubuntu/shimx64.efi
```

sda7:

```
File system:       swap
Boot sector type:  -
Boot sector info:
```

sda8:

```
File system:       ext4
Boot sector type:  -
Boot sector info: 
Operating System:  
Boot files:
```

sdb1:

```
File system:       vfat
Boot sector type:  SYSLINUX 4.07 2013-07-25
Boot sector info:  Syslinux looks at sector 98304 of /dev/sdb1 for its 
                   second stage. SYSLINUX is installed in the /uui 
                   directory. No errors found in the Boot Parameter Block.
Operating System:  
Boot files:        /boot/grub/grub.cfg /EFI/BOOT/grubx64.efi
```

**=== Drive/Partition Info ===**

Drive: sda

```
Disk /dev/sda: 698.7 GiB, 750156374016 bytes, 1465149168 sectors
Units: sectors of 1 * 512 = 512 bytes
Sector size (logical/physical): 512 bytes / 4096 bytes
I/O size (minimum/optimal): 4096 bytes / 4096 bytes
Disklabel type: dos

Partition  Boot  Start Sector    End Sector  # of Sectors  Id System

/dev/sda1               2,048       206,847       204,800   7 NTFS / exFAT / HPFS
/dev/sda2             206,848   225,282,047   225,075,200   7 NTFS / exFAT / HPFS
/dev/sda3         225,282,048 1,260,140,543 1,034,858,496   7 NTFS / exFAT / HPFS
/dev/sda4       1,260,142,590 1,465,147,391   205,004,802   5 Extended
/dev/sda5       1,260,142,592 1,299,202,047    39,059,456  83 Linux
/dev/sda6    *  1,299,204,096 1,300,178,943       974,848  ef EFI (FAT-12/16/32)
/dev/sda7       1,300,180,992 1,307,992,063     7,811,072  82 Linux swap / Solaris
/dev/sda8       1,307,994,112 1,465,147,391   157,153,280  83 Linux
```

Drive: sdb

```
Disk /dev/sdb: 28.7 GiB, 30752636928 bytes, 60063744 sectors
Units: sectors of 1 * 512 = 512 bytes
Sector size (logical/physical): 512 bytes / 512 bytes
I/O size (minimum/optimal): 512 bytes / 512 bytes
Disklabel type: dos

Partition  Boot  Start Sector    End Sector  # of Sectors  Id System

/dev/sdb1    *             32    60,063,743    60,063,712   c W95 FAT32 (LBA)
```

`blkid` output:

```
Device           UUID                                   TYPE       LABEL

/dev/loop0                                              squashfs   
/dev/loop1                                              squashfs   
/dev/loop2                                              squashfs   
/dev/loop3                                              squashfs   
/dev/loop4                                              squashfs   
/dev/loop5                                              squashfs   
/dev/loop6                                              squashfs   
/dev/loop7                                              squashfs   
/dev/sda1        18E61E35E61E139A                       ntfs       System Reserved
/dev/sda2        8272EC7172EC6AFD                       ntfs       
/dev/sda3        8E3827D73827BCD9                       ntfs       
/dev/sda5        e3e9c492-9ed2-4b3a-813f-9d35eb599066   ext4       
/dev/sda6        3F98-8CC2                              vfat       
/dev/sda7        4b3f6d97-8013-4acd-a84b-68797012834d   swap       
/dev/sda8        00a89b25-64de-40fb-aa07-b1c1e8463041   ext4       
/dev/sdb1        2665-B908                              vfat       UUI
```

`ls -l /dev/disk/by-id` output:

```
total 0
lrwxrwxrwx 1 root root  9 May 12 10:40 ata-ST750LM022_HN-M750MBB_S2SUJ9KCB27693 -> ../../sda
lrwxrwxrwx 1 root root 10 May 12 10:41 ata-ST750LM022_HN-M750MBB_S2SUJ9KCB27693-part1 -> ../../sda1
lrwxrwxrwx 1 root root 10 May 12 10:41 ata-ST750LM022_HN-M750MBB_S2SUJ9KCB27693-part2 -> ../../sda2
lrwxrwxrwx 1 root root 10 May 12 10:41 ata-ST750LM022_HN-M750MBB_S2SUJ9KCB27693-part3 -> ../../sda3
lrwxrwxrwx 1 root root 10 May 12 10:40 ata-ST750LM022_HN-M750MBB_S2SUJ9KCB27693-part4 -> ../../sda4
lrwxrwxrwx 1 root root 10 May 12 10:40 ata-ST750LM022_HN-M750MBB_S2SUJ9KCB27693-part5 -> ../../sda5
lrwxrwxrwx 1 root root 10 May 12 10:40 ata-ST750LM022_HN-M750MBB_S2SUJ9KCB27693-part6 -> ../../sda6
lrwxrwxrwx 1 root root 10 May 12 10:40 ata-ST750LM022_HN-M750MBB_S2SUJ9KCB27693-part7 -> ../../sda7
lrwxrwxrwx 1 root root 10 May 12 10:40 ata-ST750LM022_HN-M750MBB_S2SUJ9KCB27693-part8 -> ../../sda8
lrwxrwxrwx 1 root root  9 May 12 10:22 ata-hp_CDDVDW_SN-208DB_R8Y66GOCB00DST -> ../../sr0
lrwxrwxrwx 1 root root  9 May 12 10:26 usb-SanDisk_Ultra_USB_3.0_4C530001071024111481-0:0 -> ../../sdb
lrwxrwxrwx 1 root root 10 May 12 10:26 usb-SanDisk_Ultra_USB_3.0_4C530001071024111481-0:0-part1 -> ../../sdb1
lrwxrwxrwx 1 root root  9 May 12 10:40 wwn-0x50004cf2090117fc -> ../../sda
lrwxrwxrwx 1 root root 10 May 12 10:41 wwn-0x50004cf2090117fc-part1 -> ../../sda1
lrwxrwxrwx 1 root root 10 May 12 10:41 wwn-0x50004cf2090117fc-part2 -> ../../sda2
lrwxrwxrwx 1 root root 10 May 12 10:41 wwn-0x50004cf2090117fc-part3 -> ../../sda3
lrwxrwxrwx 1 root root 10 May 12 10:40 wwn-0x50004cf2090117fc-part4 -> ../../sda4
lrwxrwxrwx 1 root root 10 May 12 10:40 wwn-0x50004cf2090117fc-part5 -> ../../sda5
lrwxrwxrwx 1 root root 10 May 12 10:40 wwn-0x50004cf2090117fc-part6 -> ../../sda6
lrwxrwxrwx 1 root root 10 May 12 10:40 wwn-0x50004cf2090117fc-part7 -> ../../sda7
lrwxrwxrwx 1 root root 10 May 12 10:40 wwn-0x50004cf2090117fc-part8 -> ../../sda8
```

THIS NOT THE WHOLE REPORT... but it ends up with

```
Boot successfully repaired.
You can now reboot your computer.
```

AND

```
The boot files of [Ubuntu 18.04.2 LTS] are far from the start of the disk. Your BIOS may not detect them. You may want to retry after creating a /boot partition (EXT4, >200MB, start of the disk). This can be performed via tools such as gParted. Then select this partition via the [Separate /boot partition:] option of [Boot Repair]. (https://help.ubuntu.com/community/BootPartition)
```

This is the screenshot from gparted for the partition:
[image]

Comment: You attach the link to the Summary Report from boot repair, not load the report. You lost a lot of formatting making it unreadable. But with the now 35 year old BIOS/MBR configuration you do not need the ESP - efi  system partition. You do show BIOS boot version of grub in MBR, so did you re-install in UEFI boot mode? But then it would not ask for ESP. If booting in BIOS mode from grub in MBR, run this `sudo update-grub`.

Comment: ubuntu is now booting normally, but the windows are not showing up as a boot option

Comment: Unless both systems are in same boot mode, you will not be able to dual boot. And you cannot have two boot flags. Windows has to have boot flag on its boot partition in BIOS mode, your sda1. And UEFI has to have boot/esp flag on ESP, for UEFI boot, your sda6. And UEFI hightly recommends using gpt partitioning, your have the old MBR(msdos). Windows only boots in BIOS mode from MBR, so you need to convert Ubuntu to BIOS/MBR boot.